Fixing Height of Numbers in Libertinus Fonts
I'm using the Libertinus font set and have noticed that the digits in both the main and math fonts aren't tall enough (see photo). I've seen a suggestion to add \addfontfeatures{RawFeature={+case}}, but this doesn't achieve the desired consistency across both regular and math font sizes for the numbers. Can anyone suggest a quick fix for this issue?
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    math-style=ISO,
    bold-style=ISO,
    partial=upright,
    nabla=upright
]{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
A list of numbers in regular main font: 0123456789.

A list of numbers in math font: $0123456789$.
\end{document}



they look perfectly fine to me, I suppose in luatex you could scale the digits from Lua while loading the font,  but from xetex not so easily But really the font, as a whole, is a design choice of the font  designer and this is not a "fix" it is changing the designer's choices.

As numbers often occur in multiples, they will look very dominant compared to regular text if they have the same height as the tallest letters.

Ok, but I would appreciate an answer that achieves the effect I'm looking for.

Is there a way to match RawFeature={+case} for the math font too?

otfinfo -f LibertinusMath-Regular.otf output shows no case feature anyhow. So no, you can not apply RawFeature={+case} to Libertinus Math.

As an alternative, might it be possible to somehow change only the font of numbers in math mode to match that of numbers in the main text body (which have the +case feature)?
